# VBA if cell contain specific text then delete entire row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a VBA code that search a list of string like **[bana, app, ora]** and delete the entire row if the cells contains this.

For example:
If C6 contains the word **"apple"** or **"Application"** then the row 6 will be deleted
If H9 contains the word **"Orage"** or **"orange"** or **"oracle"** then row 9 will be deleted

Every code I found on internet is for the situation when the entire cell contains the specified string but it's not what I'm looking for.

Thank you so much for you're help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `instr()`:

```
Sub deleteTheWholeRow()

    For Each rngCell in Sheets("Somesheet").Range("A1:A50")
        If instr(1, "apple", rngCell.value) Then
            rngCell.entireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next rngCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for you're answer but when I try to add other strings like:   

If InStr(1, "app", "bana", rngCell.Value) Then
   rngCell.EntireRow.Delete

, The code says "invalid procedure, call or argument" could you help me on that please?

Comment: Yes, you can't just arbitrarily add arguments to a function, much like you can't with a cell formula. Consider instead: `If instr(1, "apple", rngCell.value) OR instr(1, "bana", rngCell.value) OR instr(1, "plum", rngCell.value) Then`

Comment: My pleasure! Good luck!

Comment: Hello, Sorry, I just tried the code now and it ends up deleting everything, even if the row doesn't have the specified string.